# Do surreal gaps have birthdays?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, surreal-numbers

Do [gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number#Gaps_and_continuity) like $\infty$ & **on** have birthdays?

I haven't ever seen anywhere that they do, & I think the answer is that they don't (although I'm not sure how to prove it).

This got me wondering, if they don't have birthdays, when do they become accessible?

Comment: The birthday of $\{L\vert R\}$ is roughly the stage at which we've built all the things in $L$ and $R$. Since in a gap one of the sides must be a proper class and at each stage we've only built set-many things, gaps don't have birthdays in any sense I'm aware of.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the comment. I guess my question could be rephrased or expanded to include: "when are proper classes born"?

Comment: That's my point: what does it *mean* for a proper class to be born? The standard usage simply doesn't make sense for proper classes. It's like asking about the cardinality of a proper class.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Bad phrasing on my part. When do we gain access to proper classes / gaps is what I'm wondering.

Comment: It's clear from your context, but there are conflicting meanings for $\infty$ and notation like $\mathrm{on}$, depending on which source you're using. And the lowercase your using is probably only used for a loopy game, rather than the "gap" you meant to suggest; $\mathrm{on}$ is a very finite graph that might be written $\{\mathrm{on}\mid\}$ or $\{\mathrm{pass}\mid\}$. In ONAG, $\mathbf{On}$ (note the capitalization) is used to denote something like $\{\text{[the class of all surreals]}\mid\}$. $\infty$ denotes a gap in ONAG, but denotes a genuine game in both Siegel and "More Infinite Games"

Comment: @user784623 "When do we gain access to proper classes / gaps" What does it mean to gain access to a proper class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technically-accurate answer is this:

There are a few different ways to define a birthday, but they are all an ordinal. No ordinal corresponds to a proper class, so a gap has no "formal birthday" by definition. (A gap like $\{\text{[class of all negative surreals]}\mid\}$ might have birthday $0$ since it should equal $0$, but no formal birthday since the left class isn't a set.) The gaps aren't part of the recursive construction of the surreals, so they can't get a birthday from the construction.

---

> When do we gain access to proper classes?

I want to emphasize that birthdays are a sort of metaphor due to the inductive definitions of the surreals. In real time, if I write down the definition of what it means to be a surreal, then I gain access to the proper class of all surreals today.

I'll write more below, but I'd say a question like this is best answered by studying set theory, and then your understanding would answer this and a million more related questions you might have.

---

Well, at any ordinal birthday, no proper class of surreals has been created yet. So if you force me invent a new metaphor to answer "when", I'd have to say "after all the birthdays".

And if you force me to give a name to the "day" or "days" that would be appropriate, maybe "the class of all ordinals" would be a candidate name, simply because it contains all the ordinals that came "before", just like a limit ordinal would.

As an aside, note that the relationship between possible sizes of the left and right classes and the birthday could fail for the gaps for set theory reasons. Without something like the [axiom of limitation of size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_limitation_of_size), a proper class could be bigger than the class of all ordinals, as discussed in [this answer of Noah Schweber](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1561623/26369).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have a suggetions for books, blogs, video series or whatever for learning more about set theory? I have been trying to decide if I should focus on learning more about set theory, category theory, type theory or ____ theory (if you have any feedback).

Comment: Additionally, do you have any comments on Conway's statements in ONAG (page 38): "Just as we speak of an infinity of objects when the collection of them is not  finite, it seems natural to speak of a University of objects when the Collection is a Proper Class. But the collection of all gaps is not even a Proper Class, being an illegal object in most set theories. Informally we may call it an IMPROPER CLASS, and speak of there being an IMPROPRIETY of gaps!"

Comment: @user784623 To really appreciate category theory, you should have a broad base of knowledge to see how it applies to many different contexts so that it is well-motivated. There is a reason undergraduates don't typically study it much. Type theory is interesting, but if you have another goal in mind (e.g. to feel more comfortable with rigorous treatments of other mathematics like CGT), then it may not be applicable to that goal. So my guess would be that learning some formal set theory would be good for you (but you won't to go too deep if you just want to apply set theory to other math).

Comment: I still don't know your background, but if there is anything in [Book of Proof](https://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/) you are not very comfortable with, I'd say start there. I don't know much about self-studying set theory since I learned about it primarily from a class following some of Kunen (which I wouldn't recommend now), but the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/389212/26369) have some suggestions. I've heard good things about Halmos's text, so maybe follow the advice in [Daniel Dinnyes's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/391677/26369) ?

Comment: My comment on those statements of Conway is: they're flowery in a fun way and grab the imagination/make me feel excited. But my understanding of the meaning of sets and classes in discussions of theories like ZFC and NBG make me sober up quickly. "If a class is a big collection of sets, what about big collections of classes?" stopped being nearly as interesting to me personally once I understood very precisely (and from a variety of sources with conflicting things to say) what the word "class" is used to mean. I would recommend focusing on standard set theory for now and then coming back to it